# Disallow item addition in a List or Doc lib

Tags: permissions

How can I disallow adding item or document to a list or document library? Due to some other feature scenario I cannot break role inheritance and have custom permission set for the list. Today, we restrict the addition using event handler (Item adding) – but this leads to poor UX.

Is there a way to have Role inheritance for a list and still have a base permission mask? Something like, allow everything that parent web offers but not X,Y,Z.  Breaking role inheritance in the traditional way introduces the problem of explicit User and role management. Having a SPGoup hold an another SPGoup could help here, but that too is not possible. Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to disallow adding an item for a user or a group?

Comment: For every one - expect the SHAREPOINT\system. My version is SP2010.

Comment: What scenario exactly stops you from breaking role inheritance? You cant have it both ways: security trimming uses... well security to trim the UI :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, I'm Kevin - the PM for permissions management in SharePoint

We don't have functionality like you describe out of the box, but Nigel's solution is pretty reasonable. You could also imagine customizing the site to remove the UI for adding items to the list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an event handler on the Item_Adding event which puts out a message when someone tries to add an item.